# $\leq$ V.S. $\leqslant$

Tags: notation

Is there a substantial difference between $\leq$ and $\leqslant$? My textbook uses both, but I could not tell why the authors selected one or the other. I asked my teacher, and she said that there was no difference between the two, but if there is no difference, why were both used? When I am writing solutions and proofs, is there any time when it would be considered better practice to use one than the other?

Comment: Poor editing?  I can't imagine why they would mean something different.  The only rational explanation I can come up with would be fonts/environments.  Perhaps in plain text $\leq$ is used and in theorem boxes $\leqslant$ is used (or vice versa or neither).

Comment: It's odd that both are used within the same text, but they're just different "fonts."

Comment: There is no difference in meaning. It's a stylistic difference only, the way  $A$ and `A` are both the letter “A”. As Jared says above, it's just bad editing.

Comment: I personally prefer $\leqslant$ and $\geqslant$. Similar to how I prefer $\varnothing$ to $\emptyset$. It's just preference.

Comment: My mobile browser finds first one easy to load! Other is a black dot for a while (till Mathjax does the magic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.decodeunicode.org/en/u+2a7d/properties

http://www.decodeunicode.org/en/u+2264/properties

Both symbols exist in unicode simply because they were both used on paper. But they mean the same.